# Why isn't this an auxiliary verb?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, should

THE EXERCISE:

> "I told my mother that my thoughts **were** bent upon seeing the world that I should never settle to
> anything with resolution enough to go through with it, and my father **should be** giving me his
> consent than force me to go without it.

In the passage, there appear to be three auxiliaries in this sentence:

1. WERE: Be Auxiliary; precedes (and inflects upon)the main verb BEND; passive construction
2. SHOULD: Modal Auxiliary; precedes the auxiliary BE and the main verb GIVE
3. BE: Be Auxiliary; precedes (and inflects upon)the main verb GIVE; active construction"

MY QUESTION:
Why isn't the first "should" an auxiliary? (*"...that I **should** never settle to..."*)

--> SHOULD: Modal auxiliary; precedes main verb SETTLE

Comment: *Were* is a linking verb here and *bent* is a past participle adjective.

Comment: The whole page has a number of typos and other errors, beyond the one Greybeard mentions in the answer below.

Comment: The passage contains several grammatical errors. "Should" is **always** a modal auxiliary verb, never a lexical verb.

Comment: The original has a comma after _world_, and reads _and my father had better give me his consent than force me to go without it_ (i.e. he would do better to give his consent).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is from https://nagelhout.faculty.unlv.edu/AGiC/s4nx.html with the commentary:

> Again, the first step is to highlight any words that might be auxiliaries:

The author has failed to notice the "should" in "that I should never settle."

Comment: One more reason not to get your ideas about grammar from the internet.